# I cannot change the opacity of titlebars in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS!

Tags: 16.04, themes, dconf, titlebar, transparency

I've used the dconf-editor and changed the
`metacity-theme-active-opacity
metacity-theme-inactive-opacity` value but nothing happen.
Can anyone help me with this. Much thanks!

Comment: Metacity was the window manager of gnome 2, so it's no longer being used. If you are using Ubuntu with unity desktop then you'll have to tweak compiz settings to achieve what you want.

Comment: You want to change the opacity of the titlebar only?

Comment: @xangua can you tell me how to do that pls

Comment: @Anwar i've changed all of the others except for titlebar, which i really like to change

Answer (score 0):

Unity does not use metacity window manager anymore. It uses it's own window manager to draw the title-bars. That's why those keys don't work in Unity. But they do still work in other gnome sessions using metacity like gnome-session-flashback.

The transparencies of title-bars in Unity is controlled by Themes. To customize the opacity of it, you need to customize the theme.